# Why does React Router not render the previous link again in a nested setup?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on an user-list project made with React/ React Router for a community I'm part of and I've been running into a problem I can not find the root of.

I have a nested Router set up, to have a userlist appear on the click of a button (url/player) and then - in the userlist - have the profile of that user appear on a click on the name (url/player/:id). This works fine so far!

BUT:
When I'm on a user profile (url/player/:id) and click the link to get back to the userlist, it does not render the userlist-component - though the url in the browser itself changes back to (url/player).

I can't figure out how to make the general userlist reappear again and would surely appreciate some input.

Since the project has multiple components, I separated them into different files, where my problem my lay.

I still tried to reconstruct the instructions of different tutorials for nested Routes. Maybe I'm just overlooking something basic, but I cant seem to find it.

**Main Navigation Router in the index.js**

```
<Router>
  <Navigation />
  <div className="contentBox">
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/player" exact component={Playerlist} />
  </div>
</Router>;
```

**Userlist Router in the Playerlist-Component**

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/player" exact component={Playerlist} />
  <Route path="/player/:id" component={Playerprofile} />
</Router>;
```

The weird thing is, only the Playerlist-Link does not work anylonger. If I click on either the "Home"-Link or any other Navigation, it works. So I assume it has something to do with the rerendering.

I'm sorry if this question seems obvious, I'm still a beginner and appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should improve the nested routing of your app:**

1. No need to wrap `PlayerList` component with `Router`. Use `Router` only in root component.
2. Don't use Route to `PlayerList` component within the component itself.
3. Do use `Route` to `PlayerList` component in *index.js*, but without `exact` (so routing to '*/player/:id*' routes work).

**Here are snippets of updated code:**

*App.js* (in your case *index.js*):

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navigation />
      <Route path="/" exact component={ Home } />
      <Route path="/player" component={ PlayerList } />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

*PlayerList.js*

```
export default function PlayerList({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Player List</h1>
      <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={ PlayerProfile } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

*PlayerProfile.js*

```
export default function PlayerProfile({ match }) {
  return <div>Player Profile { match.params.id }</div>;
}
```

*Navigation.js* (draft):

```
export default function Navigation() {
  return <nav>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/player">PlayerList</Link>
    <Link to="/player/1">Player 1</Link>
    <Link to="/player/2">Player 2</Link>
    <Link to="/player/3">Player 3</Link>
  </nav>;
}
```

Though I'd recommend to move the Links to "*/player/:id*" into `PlayerList` component.

You can find official notes on nested routing [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-nested-routing). Hope that helps.

Comment: It took a bit of fiddling (since my code is way messier than I anticipated) but it is working now. Thank you so much for looking into this for me.